# kafka-python-2.0.1 performance with large data set

Tags: python-3.x, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-python

I am using kafka-python-2.0.1 for consuming data from kafka brokers. As of now I am running a single consumer instance. We receive 2M records every 5 minutes. I noticed that kafka-python is not able to read data that faster to consume all the messages in a timely manner. I am new to kafka-python and not sure how can I put the implementation in place to read data faster. Should I run more than one consumer?

`consumer = KafkaConsumer(bootstrap_servers='<broker>',security_protocol='SASL_SSL', sasl_mechanism = 'GSSAPI', auto_offset_reset = 'latest', sasl_kerberos_service_name = 'kafka',ssl_cafile='<ca_file>',   ssl_check_hostname=False,api_version=(0,10))`

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

Depending on where your bottleneck lies, another idea might be to switch to another Kafka python library; `kafka-python` is pure python, while `confluent-kafka-python` (and optionally the apparently-dormant `pykafka`) uses a C library for performance, which it sets as a key design consideration

A [performance comparison from 2016](http://activisiongamescience.github.io/2016/06/15/Kafka-Client-Benchmarking/) reports a 9× performance difference between them

Answer (score 0):

Kafka scales with the number of partition within a topic.

If you want to increase your throughput you could increase the number of partitions of the topic. Then note, each partition can be consumed by at most one consumer within the same consumer group. So you should have the number of consumers within a consumer group match the numbers of partitions of the topic.

The consumer group can be set in the KafkaConsumer through the configuration `group_id`.